# Spring MVC - removing items using Button

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have a problem with removing objects form Map. When I click on the button all orders are removed and I have blank page, but I want to delete one object from my Map and return other on my page. Can anyone help?

This is my OrderController:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String allOrders(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("orders", orderService.getListOfOrders());
    return "orders";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String newAllProducts(@RequestParam("orderId") Long key) {
orderService.removeOrder(key);
return "orders";
}
```

and this is my orders view:

```
<c:forEach items="${orders}" var="order">
                        <h3>Order id: ${order.value.orderId}</h3>
                        <p><b>Name:</b> ${order.value.customer.name}</p>
                        <p>${order.value.customer.phoneNumber}</p>
                <form action="all" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="orderId" id="${order.value.orderId}"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete"  class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </form>
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't putting the orders into the model anywhere on your POST method.